# How to handle Notification on click navigation in Navigation Components architecture?

Tags: android, notifications, navigation, android-navigation

I am Trying to navigate on Notification  to the particular screen when  the app is already in opened state .Kindly suggest me some solution to do so.

I used only one activity and followed Navigation Components architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it in your activity. Just pass some **data payload** like the name of the fragment to open, along with your **notification payload**. Then in your activity, handle all cases to move to different fragments according to the name you'll get in the notification.